# Copying Cells Relevant to Unquie Col Match and Save to Local Drive

Tags: vba

In my workbook Inventory, I have 4 worksheets, and I would like to copy the results in Source tab to Target tab for that particular admin matching the 'Name' col in the List of Admins tab, and then save that excel file with the Admin Name on my desktop and then continue likewise until all the names under the List of Admins tab is done. The Col A has the list of unique names under the List of Admins tab.

Each of he final Excel file will be saved with only the 2 tabs Target and Instructions; the rest of the tabs must be deleted before saving.

I would like to do this since there is a huge volume of record lines for more than 1000s of admins throughout the year, and automating them was the only solution.

Comment: Automating makes sense. What have you tried? Can you paste the bit of code that you are stuck on?

Comment: I am new to VBA, and was going back and forth between the available codes trying to create VBA to execute the following, but was not able to get a complete one that get through end to end.             Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
'
    Sheets("List of Admins").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Sheets("Source").Select
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$50").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Ann"
    Range("B2:C5").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Target").Select
    Range("B7").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub

Comment: Here is the code that I have put together so far from various searches:

Comment: Sub Main()
Dim filter As String
Dim caption As String
Dim customerFilename As String
Dim customerWorkbook As Workbook
Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
Set targetWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
filter = "Text files (*.xls),*.xls"
caption = "Please Select an input file "
customerFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , caption)
Set customerWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(customerFilename)
Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Datafile1 As Worksheet
Set Datafile = customerWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set AdminList= customerWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
Set Source = targetWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

Comment: Set List_of_Admins = targetWorkbook.Worksheets(3)
Source.Range("A1", "C100000").Value = Datafile.Range("A3", "C100000").Value
List_of_Admins.Range("A1", "D100000").Value = AdminList.Range("A3", "D100000").Value
targetWorkbook.Worksheets(4).Activate
customerWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    Dim x As Integer
    Sheets("List_of_Admins").Select
    NumRows = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    Sheets("List_of_Admins").Select
    Range("A2").Select   
For x = 1 To NumRows
    ActiveCell.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Instructions").Select
    Range("C1").Select

Comment: Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks :=False, Transpose:=False
    Dim filterList1 As Variant
    filterList1 = Array("Ann", "Sarah", "Kevin", "Naomi", "James")
    filterCol1 = 1
    lastrowSrc = Sheets("Source").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    lastrowDest = Sheets("Target").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("Source").AutoFilterMode = False

Comment: Sheets("Source").Range("$A$1:$O" & lastrowSrc).AutoFilter Field:=filterCol1, Criteria1:=filterList1, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Sheets("Source").Range("A2:O" & lastrowSrc).SpecialCells (xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Target").Cells(lastrowDest + 1, 1)
    Dim save_as As Variant
    Dim file_name As String
    file_name = Sheets("Instructions").Range("C1")
    save_as = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(file_name, FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xlsm,All Files,*.*")
    If save_as = False Then Exit Sub
    If LCase$(Right$(save_as, 4)) <> ".xls" Then
        file_name = save_as & ".xls"

Comment: End If
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=save_as
'Next - repeat back to loop
    Sheets("List_of_Admins").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Next  
    Sheets("Instructions").Select
    Range("C1").Select
End Sub

Comment: Don't know how to put code onto this blog: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fcaptqiy2v9zc6t/Code%20Inventory.txt?dl=0

Comment: Edit your post to include the code. It is difficult to read when its all jammed together in 5 different comment fields. :D

Comment: I was able to place my code in dropbox and share the link here as stated in the forums.https://www.dropbox.com/s/fcaptqiy2v9zc6t/Code%20Inventory.txt?dl=0

Comment: Sorry, I'm at work and firewall blocks dropbox. :( I can try to take a look this weekend, but kid's birthday party so gonna be a busy weekend.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Main()
Dim filter As String
Dim caption As String
Dim customerFilename As String
Dim customerWorkbook As Workbook
Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
Set targetWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
filter = "Text files (*.xls),*.xls"
caption = "Please Select an input file "
customerFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , caption)
Set customerWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(customerFilename)
Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Datafile1 As Worksheet
Set Datafile = customerWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set AdminList= customerWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
Set Source = targetWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set List_of_Admins = targetWorkbook.Worksheets(3)
Source.Range("A1", "C100000").Value = Datafile.Range("A3", "C100000").Value
List_of_Admins.Range("A1", "D100000").Value = AdminList.Range("A3", "D100000").Value
targetWorkbook.Worksheets(4).Activate
customerWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
Dim x As Integer
Sheets("List_of_Admins").Select
NumRows = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
Sheets("List_of_Admins").Select
Range("A2").Select 
For x = 1 To NumRows
ActiveCell.Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Instructions").Select
Range("C1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks :=False, Transpose:=False
Dim filterList1 As Variant
filterList1 = Array("Ann", "Sarah", "Kevin", "Naomi", "James")
filterCol1 = 1
lastrowSrc = Sheets("Source").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
lastrowDest = Sheets("Target").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Source").AutoFilterMode = False
Sheets("Source").Range("$A$1:$O" & lastrowSrc).AutoFilter Field:=filterCol1, Criteria1:=filterList1, Operator:=xlFilterValues
Sheets("Source").Range("A2:O" & lastrowSrc).SpecialCells (xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Target").Cells(lastrowDest + 1, 1)
Dim save_as As Variant
Dim file_name As String
file_name = Sheets("Instructions").Range("C1")
save_as = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(file_name, FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xlsm,All Files,*.*")
If save_as = False Then Exit Sub
If LCase$(Right$(save_as, 4)) <> ".xls" Then
file_name = save_as & ".xls"
End If
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=save_as
'Next - repeat back to loop
Sheets("List_of_Admins").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Next 
Sheets("Instructions").Select
Range("C1").Select
End Sub
```